# I recently copy-pasted a code from internet. How to reset clang compiler for Mac OS 12.5?

Tags: macos, c++11, visual-studio-code, clang, clang++

```
echo 'alias g++="g++ -std=c++11"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I copy pasted this code on Mac Terminal to use C++11 by default (actually I wanted to use 'auto' keyword on my Mac). But it seems that it has altered my compiler settings and now I have to manually type in run commands everytime. E.g.:

```
g++ hi.cpp -o hi.out
./hi.out
```

How can I reset its settings to default that was working fine for me?

Comment: Does your .bash_profile  look like you expect it to? Does it have the line in question at the end?  Can you return to previous by deleting it? Does it have any similar line before? I.e. one with `alias g++` ? What was the behaviour previously? I.e. what method of doing the same did you use before?

Comment: I might have broken the intended syntax in the second shown code. Please review.

Comment: Didn't try deleting it, how can I delete that alias? please guide
I use vscode for programming and now am not able to build and run files using clang, it goes to g++ by default.

Comment: Are you aware that the first line with "echo" appends something to your .bash-profile? Are you aware of what that file does? Can you see the content of that file? Can you open it in your editor? Do you see a line appended which looks like the result of the shown code?

Comment: https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2021/09/18/cpp-en-warning-auto-extension/

I implemented solutions from this. How can I reset it to defaults as it was before, if you know?

Comment: Please correct me in any or all statement which are not true: a) you have no idea what the file ~/.bash_profile does b) you have no idea what the `>>` does c) you have no idea how the content of ~/.bash_profile looks like now d) you have no idea how the content of it looked before e) you have no idea what an alias in ~/.bash_profile does f) you have no idea what happens if you attempt to do the same alias twice. Consider explaining all of those in the question which I assume incorrectly. It would help make your question clearer and would allow to point out steps for you to find out.

Comment: I know nothing you stated above.. I'm less aware of compilers.. Just a basic competitive coder.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the file `~/.bash_profile` and remove the last line `alias g++="g++ -std=c++11"`!

On macos you can edit the file by pasting this on Terminal app:

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile
```

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25851